# Strange print behaviour in PHP?

Tags: php, echo

Why does the following code output 128?

```
<?php 
    print 4 << 5; 
?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Comment: See manual of bitwise operators: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because it's a [bitwise operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php). I think it means 4 multiplied to 2^5 because that operator means

> Shift the bits of $a $b steps to the left (each step means "multiply
>   by two")

so it's five steps. It's 4 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 (But I'm guessing here; everything happens at bit level).

Answer (score 15):

Refer to *[Bitwise Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php#example-115)*:

We have to find 4 << 5. It means shift the bits of `4` 5 times to the left:

```
4 is 00000000000000000000000000000100
4 << 5 after shifting is 00000000000000000000000010000000
00000000000000000000000010000000 is 2^7 = 2*2*2*2*2*2*2 = 128
```

Comment: +1 for the example. Reminds me I have to learn how *bitwise operators actually work*. :)