# php synatax $b = (6 << 1); clarification

Tags: php, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am not clearly understand about the following code snippets.

```
$a = (5 << 0);
$b = (6 << 1);
echo $a|$b;
```

From php.net i knew that << operator use for shift left but not clear how it works and what is the uses of | operator.
Any explanation is highly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: Php.net [examples](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) are not enough?!

Comment: `6` is `0000000000001010` binary.... shift left 1.... gives `0000000000010100`, which is decimal 12

Answer (score 0):

`5 << 0` produces just 5, since no shift is done. `6 << 1` will shift the bits in 6 (110b) one to the left, which will produce 12 (1100b). So it is multiplying by two essentially.

The | operator is bitwise or, which operates on the bits of 5 (0101b) and 12 (1100b) producing 13 (1101b)

Answer (score 0):

6 is '110' in binary. If you shift '110' once to the left you get '1100' which is 12

Answer (score 0):

`<<` is the bitwise shift left operator:

`00000110` is 6 in binary

`6 << 1` means that each bit will be shifted 1 to the left:

`00000110` (6)

becomes

`00001100` (12)

so... `6 << 1` = 12

`5 << 0` makes no difference as none of the bits are being shifted (`5 << 0` = 5).

---

`|` is the bitwise 'or' operator:

`5|12` makes:

`00000101` | `00001100`

This operator means if both bits are 0, the result will be 0, otherwise 1:

`00000101` (5)

`00001100` (12)

`00001101` (13)

So `5|12` = 13

Answer (score 0):

Hope you can find the solution here

[Strange print behaviour in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9718689/strange-print-behaviour-in-php)

for more information, you can check this link

[Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)